How to modify a positive scalar in scalar multiplication in order to get the additive inverse on twisted Edwards curves?
I know this is something possible because of Pedersen Hash : when truncating the hash to keep only the X coordinate, is it possible to compute a collision when the Babyjubjub curve is used? implies it.
So let’s say I’ve a positive scalar S1 and 2 points A and B on a Twisted Edward curve defined on a prime field such as $S1×A=B$, how to modify the scalar in order to turn $B$ into $−B$ ?
I’m meaning the coordinates of $B$ into $(−x,y)$ using the same $A$.

hint $P + [-1]P = (0,1)$, then consider the order of $P$

@kelalaka Of course, I was talking about when $B$ isn t the point at infinity.

What is the order of $A$, this is the key.

Let $A$ and $B$ be in the same subgroup with order $n$, Remember, Edward curves are not prime curves, and let

$[S_1]A = B$

then we can turn $B$ into $-B$ using
$[-S_1]A = -B$
notice that $[-S_1]A + [S_1]A = B - B$. So if one wants a little proof
\begin{align}
\mathcal{O} &= \mathcal{O} & & \mathcal{O} \text{ is the identity (0,1) }\\
A - A &= B - B\\
[S_1]A + [-S_1]A &= B - B\\
\end{align}
so, just negate the scalar of $A$, and we are done!

I forgot to add that the scalar must be >0 and the curve is defined on a prime field. Does it work is $S_1$ is equald to $A$’s order ÷2 ?

I think you are confusing the field where the curve equation is defined and the order of the curve on that field. When the order of the curve is a prime number we call it a prime curve. This work in all cases.

What I’m meaning is in addition to the prime curve, $S_1$>0 and <$A$’s order. If $S_1$ is above $A$’s order divided by 2, is it equivalent to having $S_1$ being a negative integer ?

@user2284570: remember that we always have $[S_1]A = [S_1 + kn]A$ where $n$ is the order of $A$ and $k$ is any integer (e.g. $-1$).  Hence, for any $S_1$, there's an equivalent scalar that is negative.

@poncho yes, but I want to be sure if such scalar is below the order of $A$ or if there’s an other way to achieve this.

Such a scalar is unique.
